# Angular how to parse the function below?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

how can i make my code appear on runtime when deployed  ? should i parse it and how do i parse it ? and on the console.log it shows me the array of colors

```
       console.log('colorsss')
   let colors = ['#33FFFD', '#FFD133','#FF7733','#3386FF'];  //to add my color codes
   return this.badgesColorSet[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.badgesColorSet.length)];
}
```

[image]

```
 "badgesColorSet": "['#33FFFD', '#FFD133','#FF7733','#3386FF']" //i have added this code in  turnkey-config.json
```

[image]

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand how the three lines of code you have shown are related to each other. You console log colorsss, what is that and where is it set? You then define an array of colors but that isn’t used in the next line.This last line uses a property of the current element, badgesColorSet, but where is that property defined?  Please put a working snippet into your question (not an image). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //  //gets random color out of color set from turnkey.config file for badges
    
    //     var random_color = this.badgesColorSet[Math.floor(
    //  Math.random() * this.badgesColorSet.length)];
    //  console.log(random_color);
    //     return random_color;
```